# Prepared statements in Datanucleus - MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdo, datanucleus

Can Datanucleus (with JDO) use prepare statements when dealing with MySQL?

if so - how can do I enable it?

Is it turned on by default?

**EDIT:**

 I forgot to mention: I'm using DataNucleus 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it uses those by default (for RDBMS). What else would it use?

Comment: When I add logging to MySQL, I see the actual statements being made. And well, I don't see any prepare statements, or bind variables being used. BTW, I forgot to mention I'm using 2.2.

Comment: The log tells you the *statement* SQL. It doesn't say if the object used is (java.sql.)PreparedStatement, which it is. But then you post no information, persistence operations, classes, metadata or anything to put it in context so nothing further is possible.

Comment: Wouldn't I see the MySQL native "PREPARE stmt_name FROM preparable_stmt" statements (as I see when I use them manually)?

Comment: What MySQL puts in its log is not of interest (to me). Your question is does DataNucleus use PreparedStatement, and as you can easily enough see from its code http://datanucleus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/datanucleus/platform/store.rdbms/trunk/src/java/org/datanucleus/store/rdbms/SQLController.java?revision=14813&view=markup   it certainly does.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, my question was if DataNucleus use prepare statements (RDBMS-wise), and not if it uses the PrepareStatement Java object, but I see now. Unfortunately, it does not use bind variables (at least in 2.2.4) with those prepared statements. Is that correct?

Comment: It obviously does use setXXX() method calls to set parameters in the PreparedStatement in *all* versions of DataNucleus ... if thats what you call "bind variable". Again you post no context for this so I'll leave you to it.

Comment: Or just go to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jdbcnew/  and read about "prepared statement pooling"